# How two get a substring that is in between two blocks of text in another string in Swift 2.0

Tags: xcode, string, swift, swift2

I have a string like this:

```
    let str = "<mylabel>Here is a label</mylabel>"
```

How can I get a substring with the text "Here is a label" ? Is there any fancy way to do this or do I have to use componentsSeparatedByString?
Many thanks

Comment: It looks that you are trying to parse some XML file.
Apple has native class for that https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was trying to find a "one-liner" solution without going to the full XML stuff. I used XML notation but could be anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSAttributedString(HTML:, documentAttributes:)` to extract simple HTML entities:

```
let str = "<mylabel>Here is a label</mylabel>"
if let html = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding), let result = NSAttributedString(HTML: html, documentAttributes: nil) {
    print(result.string)  // "Here is a label"
}
```

For more complex work, it would be better to use [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/) or a third-party library.

Answer (score 0):

This sorted the issue:

```
let str = "<mylabel>Here is a label</mylabel>"
let startIndex = str.rangeOfString("<mylabel>")!.last!
let endIndex = str.rangeOfString("</mylabel>")!.first!
print(str.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: startIndex.advancedBy(1), end: endIndex)))
```

Answer (score 0):

While you generally [would not want to use regular expressions to parse XML/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1271826), if you know it will have `<mylabel>` and `</mylabel>` you can do something like:

```
let result = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<mylabel>(.*)</mylabel>", withString: "$1", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)
```